# Error during recursive class template instantiation for overloaded multiplication operator in C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement a template class for a very special box, called *H Box*.
It holds a vector of numbers with the size being always a power of 2. That is essentially it, when it comes to the structure - it only contains an array and has the `[]` operator overloaded to access its elements. The thing is - it has a very fancy multiplication rules: the product of two *H Boxes* boils down to splitting vectors to left- & right- halves, creating smaller boxes, cross-multiplying them and summing up the results in the end (details in the code below). So the issue is that the multiplication operator is overloaded as a recursive function which generates smaller and smaller boxes.

I have had the code working for the non-template version of my class. However, after I moved to template I cannot get it right...

```cpp
template <typename T, const unsigned int size>
HBox<T, size> operator*(
    const HBox<T, size> &H1,
    const HBox<T, size> &H2
) {
    // recursion base:
    if (size == 1) {
        T temparr[] = { H1[0] * H2[0] };
        HBox<T, 1> H_(temparr);
        return H_;
    }
    // shared objects:
    const unsigned int halfsize = size / 2;
    T* temparr = new T[size];
    // construct helper objects:
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i] = H1[i];
    HBox<T, halfsize> H1a(temparr);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i] = H1[i+halfsize];
    HBox<T, halfsize> H1b(temparr);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i] = H2[i];
    HBox<T, halfsize> H2a(temparr);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i] = H2[i+halfsize];
    HBox<T, halfsize> H2b(temparr);
    // multiply recursively:
    HBox<T, halfsize> H1a2a = H1a * H2a;
    HBox<T, halfsize> H2b1b = H2b * H1b;
    HBox<T, halfsize> H2b1a = H2b * H1a;
    HBox<T, halfsize> H1b2a = H1b * H2a;
    // construct the final object
    HBox<T, halfsize> Ha = H1a2a + H2b1b;
    HBox<T, halfsize> Hb = H2b1a + H1b2a;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i] = Ha[i];
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i+halfsize] = Hb[i];
    HBox<T, size> H(temparr);
    delete[] temparr;
    return H;
}
```

I compile a simple test program which contains a multiplication of two four-elemental `float` boxes (`A * B`) with:

```sh
Run g++ -O0 -Wall --std=c++14 -o test test.cpp
```

And I get the following error:

```cpp
In file included from test.cpp:17:
HBox/HBox.hpp: In instantiation of ‘HBox<T, size> operator*(const HBox<T, size>&, const HBox<T, size>&) [with T = float; unsigned int size = 4]’:
test.cpp:266:44:   required from here
HBox/HBox.hpp:276:16: error: could not convert ‘H_’ from ‘HBox<[...],1>’ to ‘HBox<[...],4>’
  276 |         return H_;
      |                ^~
      |                |
      |                HBox<[...],1>
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

What has gone wrong? It seems to me that everything should be fine here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using template recursion you can't provide the base case as a simple `if`.  The reason for this is that the whole function needs to be able to compile even if some code is unreachable.  A simple `if (false)` is not enough.

To fix this you can either use C++17's [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) or [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization):

```
// using if constexpr
template <typename T, const unsigned int size>
HBox<T, size> operator*(
    const HBox<T, size> &H1,
    const HBox<T, size> &H2
) {
    if constexpr (size == 1) {
        // handle base case here
    } else {
        // handle recursive case here
    }
}
```

or

```
// using partial template specialization
template <typename T, const unsigned int size>
HBox<T, size> operator*(
    const HBox<T, size> &H1,
    const HBox<T, size> &H2
) {
    // handle recursive case here
}

template <typename T>
HBox<T, 1> operator*<T, 1>( // partial specialization for size == 1
    const HBox<T, 1> &H1,
    const HBox<T, 1> &H2
) {
    // handle base case here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if your program will never go in if statement when n != 1 your compiler is trying to compile such branch. So you can return `HBox<T, 1>` from function that have to return `HBox<T, 4>`.
First just try to add `constexpr` to `if`

```
if constexpr (size == 1)...
```

If it doesn't help try to use this code

````
HBox<T, size> operator*(const HBox<T, size> &H1, const HBox<T, size> &H2);

template <typename T>
HBox<T, 1> operator*(const HBox<T, 1> &H1, const HBox<T, 1> &H2) {
  T temparr[] = {H1[0] * H2[0]};
  HBox<T, 1> H_(temparr);
  return H_;
}

template <typename T, const unsigned int size>
HBox<T, size> operator*(const HBox<T, size> &H1, const HBox<T, size> &H2) {
  // shared objects:
  const unsigned int halfsize = size / 2;
  T *temparr = new T[size];
  // construct helper objects:
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i] = H1[i];
  HBox<T, halfsize> H1a(temparr);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i] = H1[i + halfsize];
  HBox<T, halfsize> H1b(temparr);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i] = H2[i];
  HBox<T, halfsize> H2a(temparr);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i] = H2[i + halfsize];
  HBox<T, halfsize> H2b(temparr);
  // multiply recursively:
  HBox<T, halfsize> H1a2a = H1a * H2a;
  HBox<T, halfsize> H2b1b = H2b * H1b;
  HBox<T, halfsize> H2b1a = H2b * H1a;
  HBox<T, halfsize> H1b2a = H1b * H2a;
  // construct the final object
  HBox<T, halfsize> Ha = H1a2a + H2b1b;
  HBox<T, halfsize> Hb = H2b1a + H1b2a;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i] = Ha[i];
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < halfsize; i++) temparr[i + halfsize] = Hb[i];
  HBox<T, size> H(temparr);
  delete[] temparr;
  return H;
}```
````